# Set Value Not Less Than 0 In FormArray Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular4-forms, angular-formbuilder

I have successfully implemented the value in the input field to not less than 1 in the "quantityControl" formControlName. However my problem is when on the formArray. How can i set that to not than less than 0 or should not be a negative number?

Here's the code below and the link to my stackblitz 
[CODE LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/set-quantity-not-less-than-1?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
this.inquiryForm.get('quantityControl').valueChanges.pipe(
          filter(quantity => quantity < 1)
    ).subscribe(value => {
      console.log(value);

      this.inquiryForm.get('quantityControl').setValue(1);
    });
```

Comment: the value will not be less than 1 , what is your question ??

Comment: @MuhammedAlbarmawi. My problem is how can i implement that on the FormArray

Answer (score 2):

For better understanding of Form [check here](https://medium.com/aviabird/complete-angular2-guide-reactive-forms-in-depth-part-1-21a8e2428904).

Use compose() to configure your Input field with multiple custom validations.

```
this.form = formBuilder.group({
        formControlNameValue:['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, positiveVal ])
        ]});
```

and implement positiveVal

```
static positiveVal(control:Control):{ [key: string]: any; } {
  if (Number(control.value) < 0) {
    return {nonZero: true};
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: And how can i put the error messages using *ngIf? How can i access it? Please edit my stackblitz. Thank you

Comment: a piece from my login form:::
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="username" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.username.errors }" />
        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.username.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.username.errors.required">Username is required</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

hope it helps.