# Show Error if Total Min Value Is Not Equal to Max Value

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I need to show the error if the total min value is not equal to the total max value. How will i able to do it? Here's my code and the link below [PLEASE CLICK THIS LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/set-quantity-not-less-than-1?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

```
this.total$ = this.inquiryForm.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(this.inquiryForm.value),
      map(f => f.rows.reduce(
        (acc, q) =>
          ({
            min: +acc.min + +q.min,
            max: +acc.max + +q.max
          }),
        { min: 0, max: 0 }
      ))
    );
```

Comment: where do you want to show the error ?

Comment: @MuhammedAlbarmawi. Just below each <td>
    {{ total.min }}
   </td>
   <td>
    {{ total.max }}
   </td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply be able to add a boolean property to the component and `tap()` the calculated total to set the value:

in public property section, add:

```
minEqualsMax = true;
```

In `ngOnInit()`:

```
this.total$ = this.inquiryForm.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(this.inquiryForm.value),
      map(f => f.rows.reduce(
        (acc, q) =>
          ({
            min: +acc.min + +q.min,
            max: +acc.max + +q.max
          }),
        { min: 0, max: 0 }
      )),
      tap(total => { this.minEqualsMax = total.min === total.max; }),
    );
```

Then it's simply a matter of adding your message to the template with a `*ngIf="!minEqualsMax"`

However, this will not stop the form submit as nothing is added to the form validation. If you need that, I'd suggest writing a custom validator function which iterates the `rows` FormArray to calculate values and return an appropriate error if their sums aren't equal.

A custom validator could be as simple as:

```
const MinEqualsMaxValidator: ValidatorFn = (array: FormArray): { [key: string]: boolean } => {

  const total = array.value
    .reduce((total, val) => (total.min+=+val.min, total.max+=+val.max, total), {min:0,max:0})
  const valid = total.min === total.max;

  return valid ? null : { minEqualMax: true };
};
```

Add this into the form by including it as a second argument when building the `rows` FormGroup: ie `rows: formBuilder.group([], MinEqualsMaxValidator)`.

Then you can include an error message in the form using something like this (to be added to the bottom of your current table):

```
<tr *ngIf="inquiryForm.rows.invalid && (inquiryForm.controls.rows.dirty || inquiryForm.controls.rows.touched || inquiryForm.submitted)">
  <td colspan="4">
    Validation Error!
    <div *ngIf="inquiryForm.controls.rows.errors.minEqualMax">Error: min does not equal max!</div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: You'll also need to add `tap`  to your list of imports from the 'rxjs/operators' module

Answer (score 0):

I just change Total$ to normal property `total = {max:0,min:0};` and create a method to check the state of the `total`

```
this.inquiryForm.valueChanges.subscribe(f => {
  this.total = f.rows.reduce(
    (acc, q) =>
      ({
        min: +acc.min + +q.min,
        max: +acc.max + +q.max
      }));
})
```

isTotalNotValid method

```
  isTotalNotValid(): boolean {
    let total = this.total;
    if (total.max > 0 || total.min > 0) {
      return total.min === total.max ? true : false;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

template

```
<td colspan="3" class="error">{{isTotalNotValid() ? 'Max and min can\'t be equal' : ''}}</td>
```

and you can use isTotalNotValid to disable save button

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!inquiryForm.valid || !inquiryForm.controls.rows.length || isTotalNotValid()">Save</button>
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/set-quantity-not-less-than-1-bc7jv4)

Comment: Thank you. Timshel had the answer first. Anyway, i just upvoted you. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can help my friend with his question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51737279/set-value-not-less-than-0-in-formarray-reactive-forms